# Docker error failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380:

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

**ERROR**: for app_web

```
Cannot start service app_web: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:75: mounting "/host_mnt/Users/akanwar/Documents/c/cbax-config" to rootfs at "/cbax-apply-platform/node_modules/@c/cbax-config" caused: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/a3bccebb167966c795860d95a5a758f244ae5da780f962333f0d51d2d8b2def7/merged/cbax-apply-platform/node_modules/@c/cbax-config: operation not permitted: unknown
```

STEPS TAKEN TO RESOLVE

1. deleted the docker data ran everything.
2. From Docker widget Clean / Purge data
3. From Docker widget reset to factory settings
4. docker system prune --all
5. https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1396 I followed this link as well and tried the solutions mentioned in it , but still none of it worked for me.

None of the solutions worked for me

Comment: add docker-compose.yml and the commands you run. Also if you have any custom Dockerfile, they might help in understanding what you are doing. At a first look I'd say you are mounting the volume read-only and then try to write to it....

Comment: added docker-compose.yml @Mihai

Comment: And the one you keep extending?

Comment: added  apply-platform/docker-compose.yml
@Mihai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove this from all services:

```
      - ${CBAX_PATH}/cbax-apply-platform:/cbax-apply-platform:rw
```

You cannot mount a folder and then also sub-folders. This is wrong:

```
      - ${CBAX_PATH}/cbax-apply-platform:/cbax-apply-platform:rw
      - ${CBAX_PATH}/cbax-application-pages:/cbax-apply-platform/app/assets/components/cbax-application-pages:rw
```

Also you mount a lot of host folders in multiple service with read-write access. I think that makes a mess of your files on the host if all services start modifying files. It's better to mount them read-only.

Comment: this same code worked earlier nothing changed, it is some issue with docker

Comment: no offense: you use Docker widget which tells me you are not so versed with how docker actually works. but you also don't listen to reason. that's fine. then think what changed before "it worked" and now. maybe downgrade docker until you find the version that "worked" and ignore all the security patches applied after.

Comment: Filesystems inside a Docker container work just like filesytems outside a Docker container: you need appropriate permissions if you are going to create files or directories. In this case, you're trying to create /newfolder as a non-root user.

@Mihal docker issue

Comment: @art I see you got it all under control and figured out. Except that USER is a build time directive, where creation of volumes is a RUNTIME directive. If you run a container without specifying the user then root is implied. And then volumes get created as root. You can change that with `user` in docker-compose or `--user` for `docker run` but you are not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the docker-compose file was looking for the folder cbax-config path on my machine on mac OS. MacOS doesn't have an cbax-config therefore it was not able to mount.